# Does Querydsl not support not()?

Tags: querydsl

```java
//update q_top_banner set banned = !banned where id = x;
queryFactory.update(Q_TOP_BANNER)
  .set(Q_TOP_BANNER.banned, Q_TOP_BANNER.banned.not())
  .where(Q_TOP_BANNER.eq(id))
  .execute();
```

MySQL55Dialect
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: not near line 2, column 24 [update com.gzlh.xiaolian.news.entity.TopBanner topBanner
set topBanner.banned = not topBanner.banned

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL supports it, but Hibernate does not support it in DML queries.

Instead of `NOT`, you have to use the `!` operator there. Example:

```java
queryFactory.update(Q_TOP_BANNER)
  .set(Q_TOP_BANNER.banned, Expressions.booleanTemplate("!{0}', Q_TOP_BANNER.banned))
  .where(Q_TOP_BANNER.eq(id))
  .execute();
```